# polyfill for a dependency

Tags: typescript, webpack, babel-polyfill

I have a dependency in my app which doesn't work in IE11 so I want to polyfill it but it seems it can't. Here is what I added into webpack config (jso is the library I want to polyfill):

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/index.tsx"],
```

...

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: "/node_modules/",
        include: [ '/src', require.resolve('jso')],
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        exclude: "/node_modules/",
        loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: "/node_modules/",
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: What is the `jso` module using that needs polyfilling?

Comment: ES6 classes are declared there so IE doesn't understand them